# Adding connection string to DBContext (NpgSQL, Dependency Injection, .NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am trying dynamically load up a connection string and inject it in to my DbContext inherited class.  I am not sure I am doing it correctly (can't get it to work anyway).

My MyDbContext looks like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public DbSet<Things> Things{ get; set; }

    public MyDbContext (string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns();
    }
}
```

My Startup, looks like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(s => new MyDbContext("Host=192.168.0.1; Port=4016;Database=Test;Username=test;Password=test"))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<DbContext, MyDbContext>(s => new MyDbContext("Host=192.168.0.1; Port=4016;Database=Test;Username=test;Password=test"));

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc();

        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }

    }
```

The code throws an exception on the line within Configure(...):

```
var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
```

The exception is:

> Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyDbContext'.

Comment: [Using DbContext with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core has two ways for initializing a DbContext - via dependency injection or without it. You're using dependency injection, so your DbContext needs to provide a constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions<TContext>` ([see this doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection), as @ivan-stoev wrote above).

A constructor accepting a string is only used outside of dependency injection.